# Reach router - Cannot find module './src/data'

Tags: javascript, webpack, reach-router

I have used react-router-dom 5.1.2 and now I want to switch to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reach/router Reach router (1.2.1).

I added it to the dependencies and did that:

```js
  const Home = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

```js
 <Router>
   <Home path="/" />
 </Router>
```

And now I get the following error:

```js
ERROR in ./src/polyfill.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module './src/data'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\standard\Desktop\reactjs-quick\reactjs-template\node_modules\core-js-compat\helpers.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\standard\Desktop\reactjs-quick\reactjs-template\node_modules\core-js-compat\get-modules-list
-for-target-version.js:2:51)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
 @ multi webpack/hot/only-dev-server react-hot-loader/patch ./src/main.less ./src/polyfill.js ./src/main.jsx main[3]
```

My polyfill.js looks like that:

```js
import 'core-js/stable';
```

Can someone help here ?